# PySide2 Popup - darken outside of popup

Tags: popup, pyside2, pyside6

I have created a popup window to display a custom context menu:

```py
class FileActionDialog(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_ActionDialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Popup)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
```

This is the design requirement:
[image: Design requirement]

Here is a rendered result:
[image: Rendered result]

The problem is that the outside of this popup doesn't become dark enough...
How can I darken outside?

Another example is this:
[image: Outside of dialog is blurred]

Comment: That dark area seems quite dark to me, do you actually want it *black*? And what is that behind? The whole OS, or other elements of your program?

Comment: @musicamante That is actually a required design... The popup doesn't darken outside... And the outside is just the program.. not the whole OS.

Comment: Sorry, but that's still unclear. As said, that seems dark enough, but it's also unknown how you're setting that darkening, so please clarify your post, add a more clear image and possibly another one showing the expected result.